# How to get JSESSIONID value on the first request? (coldfusion)

Tags: coldfusion, session-cookies, session-management

How to get JSESSIONID value on the first request? I spend four days on internet googling without resolving the problem
Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The jsessionid will be created by the server on the first request.

Comment: Enable `jsession` from CFAdmin. Then try dumping cookie scope.

Comment: Thank you Miguel-F and  RRK, I apologize for not reply sooner
Jsession is enabled There is no problem with session creation, but I can’t read it on the first request, I see it only on the second request (reading it from cookie)
Suppose that I want to store JSESSIONID value on db 
My code is : 
<cfif IsDefined("Cookie.JSESSIONID")> 
<cfoutput>#Cookie.JSESSIONID#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
If I close browser and execute my code on the first request I get nothing, on the second request I got it :
B4802DCD4EB90E1283E5A5CA8496FAEF.cfusion

Comment: What about session? Or in CGI scope?

Comment: same thing in CGI, the first request when Jsession is expired i get nothing, the seconde i got it

Comment: I read from other discussion on stackoverflow this note:
“This may not seem too tricky, the potentially hard part is doing it in one request, since normally a session is not created until a request is made and cookies are not set until a response is returned.”

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you actually trying to do? Why are you trying to use the jsessionid directly? The JVM is built to manage the session for you. You should not need direct access to the jsessionid.

Comment: Thank you  Miguel-F , I want to track user session, I know there is solution like GA, but I want personalize solution for specific pages campaign, so it’s better to have jsessionid for the first request stored to count session number and avrge time per session, …, instead of start from the second request if there is it

Comment: You don't need to mess with jsessionid to do that. This is my point. Just set a `session` variable and use that. Let the system handle it for you. In your Application.cfc, in the OnSessionStart method, set a session variable like `session.started = Now()`. That will tell you when the user's session was started. Then, if you want, you can do something in the OnSessionEnd method as well. Note that the session is dead at this point but you can still update a database column or some such.

Comment: [Configuring and using session variables](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/configuring-and-using-session-variables.html)